# how to receive arguments in activity extends with ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2

Tags: android, instrumentation, android-testing

Command :

```
adb shell am instrument -e  class com.vishal.nirma.test.MyActivity#MyFunction  com.vishal.nirma.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner -e myvar myvalue
```

Now,

```
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        getActivity();
        super.setUp();

// here i want to receive arguments, which are passed in command line (ex. myvar).
       // how to receive arguments here?
}
```

i am using " ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 ".

i tried bellow code in setup(), but it is not working for me.

```
Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent( ).getExtras( );


        if ( extras != null ) 
        {

          Log.v(TAG,"Parameters Received !!!");

          if ( extras.containsKey ( "myvar" ) ) 
          {
            String str_myvar = extras.getString ( "myvar" );

          } else {

          }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.v(TAG,"No parameters ???");
        }
```

it always gives me "No parameters ???".

Thanks for your help in advance ... :-)

Comment: Try using
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

Comment: getIntent() is not working with ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.

Answer (score 0):

If only it was so easy! The arguments you pass in at the command line are eaten by the instrumentation test runner, not the Instrumentation test case. This means to get hold of them you need to get ahold of the runner.

You can in fact cast Instrumentation to the test runner you are using, once you do that slightly unsafe cast then you can call getBundle() to get the arguments that where passed to it. Once you have that you can then get the values you want.